# It looks like my edit was merged with an edit by the question asker

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

If you look at [revision 2 of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29808254/revisions), it looks as if I added a whole bunch of code to the question. I just tweaked the formatting at the top and removed a tag from the title. I definitely didn't add ~5000 characters of code.

I noticed the "an edit has been made to this post" bar just before I hit submit on my edit, so I believe that what happened is that the system helpfully merged my edit with another non-conflicting edit made by OP near the same time.

Also relevant may be that the post was probably still in the edit-grace period.

Can someone say what actually happened here?

If it's intended behaviour to merge edits from different users into a single revision, I'd suggest that (at least) edits by the OP should be separated. There's a huge difference between OP adding a lot of content to a question, and JoeRandomUser adding a lot of content to a question.

Comment: You described exactly what happened.  Someone edited the post while you were editing it; the bar saying as much was not in fact lying.

Comment: Sure, but it didn't say "your edit will be merged with the other edit and attributed entirely to you"

Comment: The exact same scenario just hit me. I submitted my edit just as I noticed a new edit alert show up, and then it merged our edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You hit edit on a post with *a whole lotta code*.
2. The asker hit edit, and removed some of the code.
3. You made some other edits to the post.
4. The asker submitted his edit - as it was within 5 minutes of the question being posted, his changes were rolled into the first revision of the post.
5. You submitted your edit, still based on the initial contents of the post. It created a new revision, implicitly *adding back* the code that had just been removed.

I tend to make a habit, upon seeing that edit notification, of double-checking that the edit I'm submitting isn't/hasn't/won't inadvertently undo the other editor's changes. Even *without* the grace period revision collapsing, it's easily possible for two editors to step on each other and make inadvertent (and confusing) changes.

Comment: Ah, you're right: I didn't think the extra code was there when I originally hit edit, but I went back in my history on that tab, and it was. That must be what happened.